# MS-Access: Global Parameter for queries

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have multiple queries that use parameters like "FromDate", "ToDate"

How would I "globalize" these inside Access, so I only have to set them once and use that same values in all queries ?
Access 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to store a value that queries can use.

One of the most straightforward ways is to use a form (lets say it's called frmDate). Then add two text boxes (FromDate and ToDate). Then, in your query, you can refer to those textboxes like this: `Forms!frmDate!FromDate` and `Forms!frmDate!ToDate`.

Other ways include (but are not limited to) storing the data in a table and using subqueries or `DLookUp`, storing the data in a module and using functions to set and get it and using `TempVars`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a form, but the scope of the variables would only exist while that form was loaded. If you use a module instead and declare them as public in a global module, you wont need that form, and could use the values anywhere. Just write PUBLIC FromDate as Date at the top of the module and they should be available throughout. You will need to set their values at some time, but you wont need to redeclare them again.